# How can I specify date and time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

What is the object used in Python to specify date (and time) in Python?

For instance, to create an object that holds a given date and time, (let's say `'05/10/09 18:00'`).

As per S.Lott's request, so far I have:

```
class Some:
    date =
```

I stop there. After the "=" sign for, I realize I didn't knew what the right object was ;)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Simple example:

```
>>> import datetime
# 05/10/09 18:00
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 5, 18, 00)
>>> print d.year, d.month, d.day, d.hour, d.second
2009 10 5 18 0
>>> print d.isoformat(' ')
2009-10-05 18:00:00
>>>
```

Comment: Documentation on datetime: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html. Note that only year, month, day are mandatory when calling `datetime.datetime()`. Ex: `d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)`

Comment: In MicroPython, _datetime_ is not existing, you can use [utime](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html) instead

Answer (score 8):

Nick D has the official way of handling your problem.  If you want to pass in a string like you did in your question, the dateutil module (http://labix.org/python-dateutil) has excellent support for that kind of thing.

For examples, I'm going to copy and paste from another answer I gave a while back now:

Simple example:

```
>>> parse("Thu Sep 25 2003")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)

>>> parse("Sep 25 2003")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)

>>> parse("Sep 2003", default=DEFAULT)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)

>>> parse("Sep", default=DEFAULT)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)

>>> parse("2003", default=DEFAULT)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)
```

To ambigous:

```
>>> parse("10-09-2003")
datetime.datetime(2003, 10, 9, 0, 0)

>>> parse("10-09-2003", dayfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 10, 0, 0)

>>> parse("10-09-03")
datetime.datetime(2003, 10, 9, 0, 0)

>>> parse("10-09-03", yearfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 3, 0, 0)
```

To all over the board:

```
>>> parse("Wed, July 10, '96")
datetime.datetime(1996, 7, 10, 0, 0)

>>> parse("1996.07.10 AD at 15:08:56 PDT", ignoretz=True)
datetime.datetime(1996, 7, 10, 15, 8, 56)

>>> parse("Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD 3:30:42pm PST", ignoretz=True)
datetime.datetime(1952, 4, 12, 15, 30, 42)

>>> parse("November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am EST", ignoretz=True)
datetime.datetime(1994, 11, 5, 8, 15, 30)

>>> parse("3rd of May 2001")
datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 3, 0, 0)

>>> parse("5:50 A.M. on June 13, 1990")
datetime.datetime(1990, 6, 13, 5, 50)
```

Take a look at the documentation for it here:

http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module; there are datetime, date and timedelta class definitions.

Comment: I looked at that already but didn't knew where to start, the doc in too large

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: with a vague, open-ended question like yours, it's really hard to pinpoint the exact line of documentation that's relevant.  You could, for example, provide a code-snippet that shows what you wish to do.  You could provide a more detailed question.

Comment: I was more telling you what I've got so far than updating my question. Anyway, I've posted my current code in the question, as you see there was not much to show. :( Thanks for the link anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('05/10/09 18:00', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 5, 18, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 5, 21, 3, 55, 827787)
```

So, you can either use format string to convert to `datetime.datetime` object or if you're particularly looking at today's date could use `today()` function.